# Search/replace based on a list in a different sheet (same workbook)

Tags: vba, excel, search, replace

In my workbook, there is a sheet with list of abbreviation/full string pairs (e.g "GG" / "Gotta Go"). The sheet name is "Definitions" and the columns are C and D. The list might be updated with more pairs in the future.

Then there is a different sheet in the same workbook which contains 5 columns (P to T). These columns contain the abbreviations in random rows, some rows are empty or contain different data. The sheet name is "Target". Would there be a way to put VBA code together which would go through the pairs list and replaced the abbreviations found in cols P to T with the respective full strings? Some of the target columns may contain empty cells so if it was possible for the code to check and skip empty cells, that would be very nice.

EDIT: adding code that has kindly been put together by Mumps on Ozgrid.

```
Sub ReplaceAbbrev() 

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Dim LastRow1 As Long
Dim LastRow2 As Long
Dim foundDef As Range
Dim def As Range
Dim sAddr As String

LastRow1 = Sheets("Definitions").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row
LastRow2 = Sheets("Target").Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

For Each def In Sheets("Definitions").Range("C2:C" & LastRow1)
    Set foundDef = Sheets("Target").Range("P2:T" & LastRow2).Find(def, LookIn:=xlValues, lookat:=xlWhole)
    If Not foundDef Is Nothing Then 'if found
        sAddr = foundDef.Address
        Do
            Set foundDef = Sheets("Target").Range("P:T").FindNext(foundDef)
            Sheets("Target").Range(foundDef.Address).Value = Replace(Sheets("Target").Range(foundDef.Address).Value, def, def.Offset(0, 1))

        Loop While Not foundDef Is Nothing
        sAddr = ""
    End If
Next def

Set foundDef = Nothing
Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Please post the code you have so far.  More info at the [help/on-topic] as well as "[ask]" and also "[mcve]", and more tips on posting questions from Jon Skeet [**here**](https://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/).

Comment: Also, make it clear whether these abbrvs will be the entire cell contents. You want to avoid picking up unexpected substring matches e.g. if looking for so, for stack overflow, you don't want to be finding SOlar...

Comment: I have added the code that I am trying to use. What seems to happen is that replacements take place in all target columns (P-T), but it only for the first few "definitions" pairs. Any insight would be much helpful.

Comment: Did you see the answer?

Comment: sorry I get "Syntax error" for the row "TargetRange.Replace(DefPairsRange(r, 0).Value, DefPairsRange(r, 1).Value)". I dimension "r" as what, long?

Comment: Needs a Call statement before. I edited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Or the following which is based on matching the entire cells contents (you can change to `xlPart` for partial matches.) It is an efficient loop as you loop only the definitions, so only as many times as required. The replace works only over the populated rows of the target columns. The replace is done in one go.

```
Public Sub ReplaceAbbrev()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim LastRow1 As Long
    Dim LastRow2 As Long
    Dim targetRange As Range
    Dim def As Range

    With Worksheets("Definitions")
        LastRow1 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    With Worksheets("Target")
        LastRow2 = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "P").End(xlUp).Row
    End With

    Set targetRange = Worksheets("Target").Range("P2:T" & LastRow2)

    For Each def In Worksheets("Definitions").Range("C2:C" & LastRow1)

        targetRange.Cells.Replace What:=def, Replacement:=def.Offset(0, 1), LookAt:=xlWhole

    Next def

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Brilliant, thank you so much QHarr sir. Works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this:

```
 Dim TargetRange As range, DefPairsRange As range
Set TargetRange = Worksheets("Target").[P:T]   'Set target range

Set DefPairsRange = Worksheets("Definitions").[C1:D10] 'Set definition Range
Set DefPairsRange = range(DefPairsRange, DefPairsRange.End(xlDown))  'extend the range if need it
For R = 1 To DefPairsRange.Rows.count 'iterate through definitions and replace targets
Call TargetRange.Replace(DefPairsRange(R, 0).value, DefPairsRange(R, 1).value)
Next
```